# What is a cubic triangular number and what is a pictorial justification why a number is classified as such?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, proof-without-words

Can someone help me understand the question posed,  what is a cubic triangular number, and what is the spatial reason why a number is classified as such?

Comment: I expect that a cubic triangular number is a triangular number that is also a cube: $n(n+1)/2=m^3$. See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicTriangularNumber.html

Comment: That gives me the number, 1 which I have uncovered, and I know the mathematical relation like you posed, what does it mean spatially for a number to conform to both types.  How do I justify it not graphically in a plot, but rather in a geometric construct, in a 3d space, using a cube and a triangle.  I do not understand the reason.   If I have 1 correctly classified as such, then what does it actually mean that 1 is both a cubic and triangular number.    All I have concluded is that the number conforms to both series, if an integer.

Comment: @Vahe A single dot can represent a triangle or a cube so it is cubic triangular. 3 dots can only be arranged as a triangle so it is triangular but not cubic. Catalan's theorem proves that if you can create a triangle with more than a single dot then you can't arrange the dots into a cube

Comment: Is a representation in this case just mean a simple substitution of a shape (triangle, cube) with the dot representing that shape, forgive my redundancy in definition

Comment: Any geometric characterization is going to be messy because you're trying to combine a 2D structure with a 3D structure.

Comment: Exactly where I got confused.  Triangle is 2D, Cube is 3D, but the numbers they represent are scalars, 1D,  I am far removed from discrete math, so I am trying adhere to the right terminology to communicate properly

Comment: I think I understand, a dot is the only unit (1 - the number of such) that can be arranged both as a triangle, and a cube, because it exists as an element used to arrange both

Comment: The cube part is obvious - to get the Cuboid part use THREE dimensions n, n+1, and 1/2. You see that the unit measure gets involved.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a cuboid number or does that depend on ratios of side lengths of the cuboid shape.   In other words can a number be a cuboid such that the number of cuboids simultaneously counts into a triangle and a cuboid.   Is this version the generic form of a cubic and triangular shape.  I would think more numbers are cuboid triangular than just cubic triangular